# Downgrade rails gem with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano, rubber

I have a rails gem that I need to downgrade to an older version due to an issue with the newer version: `aws-sdk`

I've updated my local Gemfile and pushed to my git server to:

`gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'`

Now, I need to get my production server updated with the downgraded gem, instead of the newer version that it currently has.

I tried `cap deploy`, but am getting this error:

```
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] You have added to the Gemfile:
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] * aws-sdk (< 2.0)
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] 
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] You have deleted from the Gemfile:
 ** [out :: app01-myserver.com] * aws-sdk
```

So, is there a `cap` or `rubber` command that I can run from the command line that will update the Gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in error message, you should add your `Gemfile.lock` to git. After it just run `bundle update aws-sdk`, commit changes in `Gemfile.lock`, push it and deploy to the production server using `cap`.